# X.509 certificates for authentication without using client SSL

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, jboss, https

I'm trying to improve some code that enables logging in to our application using digital certificates, probably certificates stored on PKCS11 tokens.

It's a Java client server application, with the server on JBoss [Wildfly], and a rich Java thick client. We also have a GWT/Javascript based web client, but this doesn't yet support certificate auth.

The current implementation uses 2-way SSL authentication if certificate authentication is configured, i.e. the server will require a client certificate when the connection is opened. This causes some problems, and in trying to find ways to address them I've been searching madly to see if there is a standard, 'Right Way To Do PKI Auth To A JBoss Application'.

However just about everything I have found on the subject seems also to revolve around using two-way SSL, which kind of implies that *is* the Right Way to Do It.

It seems undesirable to me, in that the network transport is quite a low-level concern, heavily separated from the application logic and stuff like authentication and user management.

In order to prove the client is a valid user of the system (as opposed to merely someone with credentials endorsed by a CA in the server trust store), the server application logic has to rummage around looking to find the certificate that was used on the incoming connection in order to scrape the Common Name off it. I've discovered that `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` is a standard-ish parameter one can query on the servlet, so it ought at least to be possible.

The other architectural problem this causes is that our app requires *reauthentication* for the lifetime of certain sensitive operations. If one is using the SSL connection to prove the user has the private key, then logically that would require opening a whole separate connection.

Logically, authenticating with a certificate would seem to require

1. The server generating a nonce
2. The client encrypting the nonce using the client's private key
3. The client sending that encrypted value to the server with the accompanying public certificate [or certificate chain].

Now, that is exactly what happens during an SSL handshake, but obviously a whole load of other baggage comes with it that is irrelevant to the application-level concern of authenticating the user.

I thought about implementing the steps directly myself, but this would seem to violate the first rule of crypto (Don't implement your own crypto).

If the server generates random nonces then that introduces a level of chattiness and statefulness to the process, which is doable but a pain when you are striving for a stateless and clusterable server.

Time-based One-Time Password implementations circumvent this, and seem to be a standardized mechanism for 2-factor authentication that is getting support from Google+ and the like.

However I can't find anything in the way of out-of-the-box libraries that will let me build an implementation using certificates directly from an imposed PKI.

Comment: So you want to use certificates to authenticate a user but not for encrypting the connection?

On a side note: Did you consider using SSO and handling authentication outside of the application?

Comment: Well, there will still be one-way SSL, so the connection will still be encrypted. It's just that tying auth to the connection causes problems. I think that SSO might well be the right way to go - then it becomes someone else's problem! Moreover there is something more natural about opening short-lived connections to a 3rd-party system for authentication and reauthentication.

Comment: I am curious to get opinions as to why/whether two-way SSL really is the only common way to do cert authentication. I can understand that an SSL handshake does all of the things that the narrower problem of cert authentication needs, but it still seems to be conflating two very different application layers. Maybe I'm wrong and it really is The Right Way To Do It, rather than the Only Regular Out Of the Box Way To Do It.